# Anchoring excel Userform in a fixed position in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have defined an Userform in excel vba and I am trying to *permanently display* it in a *fixed position* of certain worksheet when this worksheet is shown on my screen (see note 1 below).

I have tried in many ways but the most I have got is to fix the userform *on my screen* but -instead- I need to do it on *a particular worksheet*.
Does anybody know if my target is feasible and how to get it?
Any hint will be highly appreciated

Note 1: in other words I am trying to use the userform as if it was a frame with some activeX controls embedded in the worksheet

Comment: You could hide the UserForm in the deactivate event of the desired worksheet, and show it again in the activate event for that worksheet.

Comment: @SpectralInstance OK, but anyway, it remains the fact that the userform is positioned respect to screen and not to a fixed position inside the worksheet...

Comment: @Guille Have you looked at the `Startup Position` property of the UserForm? It sounds as if yours is set to Center Screen. Perhaps one of the other choices would be better. Center Owner would put it in the middle of the Excel application.

Comment: @Ron Yes, but it does not do what I want. StarupPosition just "Returns or sets a value specifying the position of a UserForm when it first appears. " (from MS site).
What I need is that the position INSIDE THE SPECIFIC WORKSHEET is maintained when one moves along it. A kind of embedding the userform in the worksheet. Unfortunately I am starting to think that it is not possible in a clean and simple way.

Comment: @Guille I don't see that as a property of the user form.

Answer (score -1):

That would be nice if it could be fixed like you want. I am about at dumb as "you know what" when it comes to Exel, but if I'm correct you cannot click on any other Macros or cells other than what you have in the userform when activated. I have a userform and in the settings I have set the Start Position  to 0 - Manual. What this does is when the form is activated you can drag it to where you want it to be, and it will pop up there every time you activate it. However, when you close or exit your program and restart you will need to reset or drag it back to where you want it. This works for me so maybe this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: A Userform can be Modal or Modeless. [The ShowModal property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/showmodal-property)